Network Manager keeps asking for "Legitimation for WIFI"
I have an elderly person whose desktop is connected to the LAN via WIFI card.
The WIFI is always the same, "Allow all users to connect" is already checked, the main user gets automatically logged in.
Sporadically, Network Manager will popup a dialogue titled "Legitimation for WIFI password" which my elderly person thinks is kind of a scam and always calls and asks me about. I mean, I love that they do ask instead of just pressing buttons, but I'd like for them to not be bothered by this. Due to the placing of the computer, I'd say it is losing the WIFI signal once and again. But maybe it's just because of some NM quirk...
The correct password is already inserted, all my elderly person would have to do is press "connect", but... well. Elderly person.
I've already edited the wpa_connect.conf and given it all relevant data (WPA-PSK, ssid). I plan on checking the dhcpd.conf too, but right now I am (again) cut off from said elderly person's PC.
So, regarding that there is no roaming involved, how can I make sure that the computer will just reconnect to the local WIFI whenever it gets cut off, without asking any questions?
Thanks.

It may have sporadic access to another network nearby. Did you make it "forget" all other networks?

IIRC was it never connected to any other network, but I'll have a look into that.
